# If input value equals to Div's ID, then show it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, show

I'm trying to create simple dictionary web-page and I need to show certain DIV with word's translation and description which is entered in INPUT.

I've created some simple JavaScript for that, but I want to use about 50 words and not planning to create 50 scripts for that :D.

```
var match = 'cat',
    input = document.getElementById('searchbox'),
    div = document.getElementById('cat');
    input.onkeyup = function(e){
    if (this.value == match){
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Instead of that I want to use something different. My goal is to achieve something like that - If text entered in INPUT equals to one my DIV's ID than show it.

For example if visitor typed "CAT" in INPUT than show DIV with "CAT" ID and so on. One script instead of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function in javascript like this and call this function on click of a button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fSDiv(var txt,var EId)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(EId).value === txt)
             {
                document.getElementById(EId).style.display = "block";
             }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element exists using the `typeof` keyword like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchbox');
var div = document.getElementById(input.value);
if(typeof(div) !=== 'undefined') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
```